# variance of multiple varibales

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Mean or $E(X)$ is linear, so it's valid to write $$E(x_1 + x_2 + x_3) = E(x_1) + E(x_2) + E(x_3)$$ But $Var(x)$ is not linear, so we write $$Var(ax_1 + bx_2 ) = a^2Var(x_1) + b^2Var(x_2) + 2ab\;Cov(x_1,x_2)$$ In the following question finding mean is easy and I'm getting it $40$mm. But I'm finding it difficult to get the variance because it is non linear operation. Any suggestion on how to solve such type of questions.

> Q. The mean thickness and variance of silicon steel laminations are $0.2$ mm and $0.02$ respectively. The varnish insulation is applied on both the sides of the laminations. The mean thickness of one side
>   insulation and its variance are $0.1$ mm and $0.01$ respectively. If the transformer core is made using
>   $100$ such varnish coated laminations, the mean thickness and variance of the core respectively are ?

Answer is $40$ mm and $0.24$.

Comment: Variance is given in mm, $0.02$ mm or something smaller like $μm$? Also, use independce to get rid of $Cov$. Lamination $X_1$ and insulation $X_2$ are independent, so $Cov(X_1,X_2)=0$.

Comment: No unit is specified in the question. If I use independence, variance of single varnished lamination is $0.02 + 2^2 * 0.01 = 0.06$, so of 100 such lamination will be $100 * 0.06 = 6$. But this is not the write answer.

Comment: That is why I ask about the unit. Because if it is 0.2 and 0.01 instead then you have 0.2+2^2*0.01=0.24. But then it will be 100^2*0.24 which is more than 2.4 mm. But looks more like it, so could be correct with the right units

Answer (score 0):

Here is a note from my ignorant inspection:

thickness per lamination * number of laminations = mean thickness = (.2mm + 2*.1mm)*100 = 40mm